# How to write a script to login into ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I want to write an application in python that -

> 1. uses Face Recognition to login to ubuntu.
> 2. Uses Face recognition to authenticate a root user when running some command in terminal

I've used Opencv for face recognition. I have trained my recognizer with a set of faces and in a database I am storing the password corresponding to that user. I capture video from webcam frame by frame and Once a face in frame matches corresponding password is read from Database.

Now I don't know-

> 1. how to login once a face is matched ?
> 2. How to run my face recognition script whenever a command requires sudo/ root permission ?

Comment: Can you stick to one question for your question? Your question is about how you log into an Ubuntu system using a Python script - what have you tried so far? What have you done?

Comment: I have no clue how to login to ubuntu using a script.
So far I've been able to create a script in python which when run starts capturing frames from webcam,detects face in the frame, matches it to it's trained set, if a positive match then password from database is fetched and printed in terminal.

I want this script to run whenever I am on the lock screen, if positive match then login.

Comment: Look into [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM) -- Pluggable Authentication Modules. You could create a PAM module that uses face recognition and then configure the PAM stack in, say, `/etc/pam.d/common-*`, to call your module.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks, I'll look into it.